# Undelete button incorrectly says 2 undelete votes remaining, when in truth I have none

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-undelete

I cast some undelete votes, with the undelete dialogue claiming I have 2 votes remaining.  In reality, I have used my 5 undelete votes, and I am unable to cast any more.  The "Vote to undelete this post?" dialogue box is incorrect.

[image: undelete screenshot]

Comment: did you click that undelete link directly after a page load? Or was it already open in a tab while you were casting undelete votes?

Comment: @rene It was already open (I opened a bunch of recently deleted posts in different tabs, went through them one by one, cast undelete votes on some).  Perhaps one of the numbers gets loaded dynamically while the other gets loaded just once?

Comment: Yeah, the dialog value is fetched on load, the error-checking is real-time and is the error-response from the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Information about votes is not always updated in pages that you already have open.  I've seen "misfires" when voting to close or delete when something changed since I loaded the page.  (I think I've seen similar odd behavior with posts that became locked while I was trying to do something, but I might be misremembering.)

The general rule is that the server doesn't push *everything* to already-loaded pages; developers made decisions based on cost versus inconvenience.  When in doubt, reload the page.